# Как отключить список в Spinner?

Tags: android

Есть Spiner где всего одна Запись String asd2[]={"1"};
Если нажать на Spinner то откроется Spinner и там будет написано 1 также в выпадающем списке 1.

Есть ли в Spinner галочка в Xml чтобы отключить открывать списку когда внутри меньше 1 записи, ну или как называется метод который запрещяет октрываться списку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: И чо типо во время нажатия делать проверку. Но в Spinner  же не работает setOnClick

Comment: @xTIGRx Просто добавьте это в `onCreate` активити/ `onCreateView` фрагмента и `Spinner` стать должен некликабельным.

Comment: Эмм, но мне так то надо чтобы он был кликабельным

Comment: А зачем его кликабельным делать, если в нём только один пункт? Если больше - ставьте обратно `spinner.setEnabled(true);` Вы ж сами написали, что надо предотвратить раскрытие списка...

Comment: Дак вот чтобы его обратно выставить мне нужно прописать это в setonclick, а он не работает у Spinner

Comment: В теории можно обернуть Spinner в другой вью и вешать слушатель на него.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб. Думал сам так ответить автору, но вы опередели, реально можно унаследоваться от Spinner и добавить ему возможности отслеживания нажатия через OnClick и применять к нему соответствующие действия и плов готов.